# Match lines with "1" before 1st-occurence of "xyz"

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-negation

Im looking for a PCRE-regex to match lines with "**1**" before the first-occurrence of "*xyz*", so with lines like...
Anytext**1** Anytext2 *xyz* Anytext1 xyz AnyText1 xyz
Anytext0 Anytext2 *xyz* AnyText1 xyz Anytext1 xyz AnyText1 xyz AnyText1 xyz

Only Line1 should be matched, is this possible?

EDIT:
If look-behinds supported variable-quantifiers, I'd just use `^(.*?xyz)(?<=.*1.*xyz).*`
That could match the first *xyz*, then lookbehind for '**1**' somewhere.

String-lengths vary and '**1**' can be anywhere, so I cant use multiple lookbehinds with single-quantifiers.
Like if my strings were always 17-chars before *xyz*, I'd still need 17 different look-behinds like...
`^(?:.*?xyz)(?<=.{7}1.{10}xyz).*`    (matching '1' as the 8th-char, like on Line1)
`^(?:.*?xyz)(?<=.{8}1.{11}xyz).*`    (matching '1' as the 9th-char)
Lol, except 15 more to match all 17 positions, and my strings arent always 17-chars long anyway.

SOLUTION:
Luckily, @The Fourth Bird and @vszholobov instead offered solutions to use a negative look*ahead*.
Use `(.)*` with a negative lookahead just before **.** to test that if **.** matches, its not *'x'* followed by *'yz'*.
So the solution I ended up using, looks something like...
`^((?!xyz).)*1.*xyz.*`

It only matches when '**1**' appears before the very first '*xyz*' in any string.
Just insert ?: into the first group if you dont want any group consumption.. Thanks again everyone!!

Comment: `/^((?!xyz)[^1])*((?<!xyz)1)/gm` try this.

Comment: Do not cross matching xyz or 1, then match `1` and match xyz `^(?:(?!xyz|1).)*1.*xyz.*` https://regex101.com/r/Qzf5fw/1

Comment: @K450 **Thanks** but no luck. If _only_ look-behinds had variable quantifiers, I'd use ^(.*?xyz)(?<=.*1.*xyz).*
Wish I could use multiple look-behinds with single-quantifiers, like ^(.*?xyz)(?<=.{7}1.{10}xyz).* for Line1.
Unfortunately, my strings not only vary in length, but that darned "1" could be anywhere within the string.
Right now I just cant think of another way around this. At first I thought I was just having a brain fart, but maybe its not so easy after all?

Comment: @The fourth bird **Thanks** for this! I was so focused on using look-behinds, I didnt even consider a look-ahead with an alternate. Thanks again.

Comment: @evangeline531 Can you update your question with what you have tried that you have stated in the comments?

Comment: @evangeline531 I have added it as an answer.

Comment: @The fourth bird and vszholobov.. I tried to upvote your answers, but it keeps saying that I need to have "at least 15 reputation to cast a vote"! I think the upvotes will eventually appear, because it also says... "but your feedback has been recorded". Anyways, I just wanted to thank both of you again!

Comment: @evangeline531 That is ok, glad it worked for you :-)

Answer (score 1):

You need to match line if its part before `1` first occurrence doesn't contain `xyz`. It is doable with negative [look-arounds](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

[Example](https://regex101.com/r/VcMJqC/1).

More information about matching line which does not contain a word [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/406230/15777370).

Answer (score 1):

You could use use a negative lookahead to match a single character when either a `1` or `xyz` is not directly to the right.

Then you can match the `1` and match `xyz` in the string.

```
^(?:(?!xyz|1).)*1.*xyz.*
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:` Non capture group to match as a whole part

  - `(?!xyz|1).` Negative lookahead, assert not `xyz` or `1` directly to the right
- `)*` Close non capture group and optionally repeat it
- `1.*xyz.*` Match `1` and then `xyz` in the string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Qzf5fw/1)